# Images to Target Specific iPhone Models

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, swift, target

Say I have an image which is half the height of an iPhone 4s screen display, when this image is loaded to an iPhone 5 clearly this size is no longer half the size of the iPhone, as the iPhone 5's height is slightly larger then the iPhone 4s.

My question is, like using the image 2x and 3x, is there a way of adding images to your app that target specific iPhones? So that the other images not targeted will not be downloaded with the app.

Or will I need to add images of various sizes to the app and then in the code, say if iphone4 load this image, if iphone5 load this? The only reason I don't want to do this is because I will have 3x the amount of stored images (target iPhone 4, 5, 6) than I would for the iphone6 plus or iPad.

What I was hoping for something like image@2x~iphone4.png or image@2x~iphone5.png, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David Cao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295664/2613662) is correct for bundled image assets, but you have mentioned that you don't really want to include this many assets with the app.

You may want to look at the [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) features of Xcode 7 / iOS 9, along with On-demand Resources this will allow you to load your required images into Xcode but the App Store would only download the resources required for the device being used.

If you still need to support iOS 8 you would need to have the images stored on a remote server and load them in when needed.

Comment: From the looks of it 'app thinning' will be a great feature once it is available. But for now, until it's available, I just have my app larger then it needs to be, as I don't think I'm going to setup a remote server. Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at image assets, it solves the exact problem you've stated. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

What it does is allows you to provide 1x, 2x, and 3x images which can be referenced as a single name, when you call `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNameHere"]`.

Comment: It sort of does, but 2x targets iPhone 4, 5 and 6 and each of these iPhones have different heights. I haven't looked at the link yet, which I'll do now, but if it's in regards to the 1x, 2x and 3x, I don't think it works for my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, well you can always get the height of the screen by calling '[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds', and pick the image accordingly. I personally don't like using this method, since I'd need to have an image for each device. I usually draw a background haha. Also, if your image can be stretched, just get half the height of the screen and scale it accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I thought able stretching the image, but unfortunately I can't do this with the specific images I have. Thanks for your post though.